# Влияет ли if на контекст this?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Влияет ли `if(условие){код с this}` на контекст this?

Comment: Новый `this` создают только функции.

Comment: @Aid, стоит заметить, что "стрелочные функции" не создают свой контекст, а используют контекст, в котором они объявлены (лексически привязаны к `this`)

Comment: @alvoro, Тогда можно вспомнить всякие `bind` или `call`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет

```js
function someFunc() {
    console.log(this);
    var that = this;
    if (true) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this === that);
    }
}

someFunc.call("Iam context");
```